# How to prevent function to do something if it reaches its "if" statement?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexs to do some action. So here is the goal:
When the element "one-third" (it is highlighted with text of pxl width) reaches width of 300px it has to add the class so the element gets 100% of element width. But wneh it gets full-width the function recalculates its width value and the elements start to blink. See the code snippet to understand the issue.

```js
function check() {
  var width = $('.one-third').outerWidth();

  if (width < 300) {
    $('.one-third').parent().addClass('to-column')

  } else {
    $('.one-third').parent().removeClass('to-column')

  }
  $('.one-third').text(width)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  check()
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  check()
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #C38D94;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
}


.fbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
.one-half:after, .one-third:after, .one-four:after, .one-five:after, .one-six:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.one-half:after {
  content: '2';
}
.one-third:after {
  content: '3';
}
.one-four:after {
  content: '4';
}
.one-five:after {
  content: '5';
}
.one-six:after {
  content: '6';
}
.one-half, .one-third, .one-four, .one-five, .one-six{
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #565676;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
.one-half {
  flex: 1 calc(50% - 4px); 
  min-width: 300px;
  }

.one-third {
  flex: 1 calc(30% - 4px);
  
}
.one-four {
  flex: 1 calc(25% - 4px);
  
}
.one-five {
  flex: 1 calc(20% - 4px);
  
}

.one-six {
  flex: 1 calc(15% - 4px);
  
}
.one-third-full {
flex: 1 100%;
}

.to-column {
  flex-flow: column
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fbox dns">   
  <div class="one-third exmpl"></div>
  <div class="one-third exmpl"></div>
  <div class="one-third exmpl"></div> 
</div> 


<div class="fbox"> 
  <div class="one-half"></div>
  <div class="one-half"></div>
</div>
  
 <div class="fbox">  
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div> 
</div> 
   
<div class="fbox"> 
<div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
</div>
  
  <div class="fbox"> 
  
  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
</div>

<div class="fbox"> 
  <div class="one-half"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
</div>
  
  <div class="fbox"> 
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-half"></div>
</div>

<div class="fbox"> 
<div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
</div>

<div class="fbox">
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="truth"></div>
```

So the question how to solve it?
Also code [here.](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/OyeGJW)

Comment: `if ( width < 300 && !$('.one-third').parent().hasClass('to-column')) {`

Comment: not helped in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `if` statement like following.

```
if (width < 300 && !$('.one-third').parent().addClass('to-column').hasClass('to-column')) {
   $('.one-third').parent().addClass('to-column')
}
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/azim101/8xkf8ntg/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: No its not what I am looking for. I need function to: if the width of element is less 300px, then to add class "to-column". But the thing is that after statement becomes false because the width becomes more then 300px. I'm trying to get the right logic to build adaptive struction to use flexbox and scripts.